# What does a coordinate representation of density matrix mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

A coordinate representation of density matrix $\rho$ is defined as

$$ \rho (x, x') \equiv \left<x\right| \rho \left|x'\right> .$$

When $x = x'$, this expresses a probability where a particle is in the state $\left|x\right>$.

Question: what does that mean when $x \neq x'$? Is that related to some probability?

---

According to Feynman (*Statistical Mechanics a set of lectures, (p.72)*),

$$ I \equiv \int dx _1 \int dx _2 \cdots \int dx _{n - 1} \left<x\right| \rho \left|x_1\right> \left<x_1\right| \rho \left|x_2\right> \cdots \left<x_{n-1}\right| \rho \left|x'\right>$$

can be interpreted as that "the particle travels from $x'$ to $x$ through a series of intermediate steps, $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{n-1}$, which define a path". I don't understand this statement.

Comment: Could you provide a reference with that specific form of the path integral, involving $\rho$? The interpretation about the particle travelling from $x$ to $x'$ is correct, but I have never seen it with $\rho$ before...

Comment: @SuperCiocia I added the book name in the post.

Comment: On page 72 I see the usual definition of the path integral with Hamitlonians, not your expression with *just* the density matrix. The idea of the path integral is to start with an initial state $|x\rangle$, "evolve" it $e^{-iHt}|x\rangle$, and then find the overlap with a different position $\langle x'|e^{-iHt}|x\rangle$ to quantify the probability it has to move from $x$ to $x'$. But you need something to let it "evolve". In your cane $\langle x|\rho|\rangle = \langle x|\Psi\rangle \langle \Psi |x\rangle$ just gives the combined probability of being at $x$ and at $x'$.

Comment: @SuperCiocia So you thankfully checked the book? How kind! Your explanation of the path integral seemed clear and straightforward to me. I now understand what the author wanted to say. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The diagonal entries of the density matrix are called **populations** and provide information about the *probability density* of the particles (described by the density matrix), i.e. their probability of "being found" in real space.

This is easily seen from a density matrix $\rho = |\Psi\rangle \langle \Psi|$, and $$\rho(x,x) = \langle x|\rho|x\rangle = \langle x|\Psi\rangle \langle \Psi|x\rangle = | \langle x |\Psi\rangle|^2 = |\psi(x)|^2,$$ which is the usual quantum mechanical probaibility density.

The off diagonal entries of the density matrix are called **coherences** and provide information about the *phase coherence* of the system described by $\rho$ between two positions $x$ and $x'$. Is there a fixed phase relationship between $x$ and $x'$, especially as $|x-x'|\rightarrow \infty$? I.e. will constructive & coherent interference occur over a large distance or will it be washed out?

The most famous application of the off diagonal elements of the density matrix is in *Off-Diagonal Long-Range Order* (ODLRO), which is what manifests in Bose-Einstein Condensates or Superfluids. These are phases where the system breaks a $U(1)$ phase and the wavefunction "picks" a specific phase $\theta$.

The "broken" phase is distinguished from the unbroken phase because it obeys:
$$ \lim_{|x-x'|\rightarrow \infty} \rho(x,x') \rightarrow n_0 \neq 0,$$ i.e. phase coherence is preserved over arbitrarily long distances.